# Question regarding notation of definition of operations on set families

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Are those two notations saying the same? If not, how can the text in the first equation be avoided?

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} M := \{ x \in G | x \in M_i \text{ for all } i \in I \}$$

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} M := \{x \in G | \forall i \in I : x \in M_i\}$$

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer @Berci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. $\forall$ does exactly mean "for all". If you replace the symbol there are hardly any differences at all, besides order.